# Aptana + XDebug over Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, aptana, xdebug, aptana3

I'm trying to get XDebug to work on Aptana 3 Studio, running in Ubuntu Linux. I'm using a xampp installation for Apache + PHP. I've been reading and I get that there was not support for XDebug in studio 3.0 until recently.
It seems that I've been able to install XDebug following some of the content of this ticket
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-769 but
-I don't have a lot of experience on this matters
-I'm a newbie using Ubuntu
-the ticket has a thoroughly explanation to configure everything in windows, it's not the same

I have my Xampp server intalled in /opt/lampp with default options (and the site I'm trying to debug is at /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite)

Apparently I can debug a single file, running Debug/Debug as/PHP Script, but I'm trying to debug a WordPress installation on my localhost (I'm dealing with a customized plugin) so I tried Debug>Firefox - internal Server.

Than opens a new firefox window, shows "Aptana Firefox extension launching ... please wait" (but despite it's on firefox, the url says 
chrome://aptanadebugger/skin/init.html)
and then I have an error message:

Launching Firefox - Internal Server has encountered a problem
Socket connection error. Please try shutting down and restarting your web browser, and then run "debug" again

I know I'm probably missing some needed information, I'm completely lost here. If there is someone who could help me about how to configure my environment I would highly appreciate tips or any kind of enlightment.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just downloaded and began running Aptana Studio 3 on Linux Mint. I was getting the same Socket connection problems until I actually "activated" the firebug icon in the top right of Firefox. There is a drop-down arrow next to the little bug icon and one of the options is, "On for all Web Pages." Once I turned that on, I no longer get the socket connect error. Good luck!